# Active record query enum column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a query that looks like this

```
where("user_id = ? OR privacy = ?", user_id, :public_activity)
```

And the enum

```
enum privacy: [:public_activity, :friends_activity, :private_activity]
```

`:public_activity` doesn't work in this query and just gets sent as a string. Is there any clean way to write this query without just using an integer which will be hard to understand when reading the query?

Comment: What is `:public_activity`? Just a key in an `enum`? The name of a method that you want to call?

Comment: @spickermann Updated with that info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use key in order to fetch integer, here is an **example**:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class Model < AR
  enum privacy: [:public_activity, :friends_activity, :private_activity]
end
```

Fetch status integer:

```
Model.privacies[:public_activity] => 0
```

The `where` method:

```
where("user_id = ? OR privacy = ?", user_id, Model.privacies[:public_activity])
```

[Read documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Answer (score 2):

Following the [documentation of `enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) you should be able to use the scope that is defined by `enum` automatically:

```
Model.where(user_id: user_id).or(Model.public_activity)
```

Comment: This will generate `AND` sql query not `OR`.